# NoodleLineNumberView, the numbers are not aligned properly, not sure whats wrong

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add line numbers using [NoodleLineNumberView](https://github.com/MrNoodle/NoodleKit). The issue I'm having is that the line numbers dont line up properly with thier line number.I have to type 16 lines, then line 1 gets marked as line 16. If I scroll down past the top of the text I can see the other line numbers there, its just like all over the are shifted up.

I subclassed a `NSScrollView` and added this bit of code. Thats all that should be needed. Is anyone else having this issue, or solved it?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.gutter = [[NoodleLineNumberView alloc] initWithScrollView:self];
    [self setVerticalRulerView:self.gutter];
    [self setHasHorizontalRuler:NO];
    [self setHasVerticalRuler:YES];
    [self setRulersVisible:YES];
}
```

[image: Error]